# Linear Gradient: Safari vs. Chrome

Tags: css, safari, gradient, opacity

I am having an issue where a gradient which transitions from transclucent (~.1 opacity) on the edges of the page to solid white appears lighter on the edges in Safari. In Chrome and Firefox the edges are the darkest. In Safari it seems that a white background is being assumed that it added to the gradient. Thus, the edges are lighter than the middle of the gradient, as the gradient transitions from translucent to opaque white.

The page in question can be found [here](https://theline.design/2016/10/17/hello-world.html).

The relevant CSS is:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, 
rgba(100,100,255,0.15) 0%,
rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%,
rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%,
rgba(100,100,255,0.15) 100%);
```

A screenshot of this CSS looks like [image: without background color] this: I have tried adding a "fallback color" (really a background-image) to the CSS to help Safari, since it seems to be assuming a white background which, when added to the translucent rgba(100,100,255,0.15) makes for lighter edges. However, this just makes everything darker and doesn't overcome the lightness of the edges. The result of that can be seen in the below screenshot. The CSS for this was:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, 
rgba(100,100,255,0.15) 0%,
rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%,
rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%,
rgba(100,100,255,0.15) 100%)
rgba(100, 100, 255, .15);
```

This looks like: [image: with background color]

Comment: What version of each browser?  They look the same over here...

Comment: @anied, I'm sorry to have not given my answer. If you inspect the page you will see that I am no longer using opacity transitions in my gradient. It doesn't make sense and it isn't the right thing to do. Thanks for confirming that they look the same!